# plotting $\frac{-\pi}{2}<x<\frac{\pi}{2} $ and $ 0<y<1$ under mapping $w=\sin(z)$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

i need to plot this $\frac{-\pi}{2}<x<\frac{\pi}{2} $ and  $ 0<y<1$ under $w=\sin(z)$ mapping so what i did is $ y=0 , \frac{-\pi}{2}<x<\frac{\pi}{2} => -1<u<1 , v=0 $
 $ y=1 , \frac{-\pi}{2}<x<\frac{\pi}{2} => (\frac{u^2}{\cosh(1)^2})+(\frac{v^2}{\sinh(1)^2})=1 $
 $ x=\frac{\pi}{2} , 0<y<1 => 1<u<\cosh(1) , v=0$ $x=\frac{-\pi}{2} , 0<y<1 => -1<u<-\cosh(1) , v=0 $
 now how should i plot

Comment: Is it true that $z=x+iy$ and $w=u+iv$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got it, all you need to do is to combine these into a plot.

I guess you want something like this?

[mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5krSM.png)

#### edit

*error in the picture, it should be the upper half of the ellips.

Because when $$\gamma = \frac{\pi}{2}t + i \quad\text{then}\quad \sin(\Gamma) = -\cosh 1 \sin\frac{\pi}{2}t +i\sinh 1 \cos\frac{\pi}{2}t$$

Meaning if $t = 0$ then this evaluates as $0+i\sinh1$

Comment: yes i need to know how to draw the plot with these stuff that i got

Comment: Just draw all of the borders and look what region it encloses? The ellips uses the bottom half because $$\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}t +i) = \cosh 1 \cdot \sin\frac{\pi}{2}t -i \sinh 1 \cos \frac{\pi}{2}t$$ where if $t: 1\to 0\to -1$ means $w: \cosh 1 \to -i\sinh 1 \to -\cosh 1$.

Comment: the answer that i had was [this](http://tinypic.com/r/2py17cx/8) , so it is wrong ?

Comment: 1) I've made an error in my calculations. $$\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}t +i) = -\cosh 1 \cdot \sin\frac{\pi}{2}t +i \sinh 1 \cos \frac{\pi}{2}t$$ Meaning you should take the upper half of the ellips. 2) Why did you exclude an inner circle? Let $\Gamma = it$ with $t: 0\to 1$. Then $\sin(\Gamma) = i\sinh(t)$ so the points on the imaginary axis should be included since $i\sinh(t)$ goes from $0 \to i\sinh 1$.

Comment: yes , that is correct ,thank you

Comment: @dietervdf for this question given that $w=-\sin(x)\cosh(y) + i\cos(x)\sinh(y)$ and $\therefore \color{green}{u=-\sinh(x)\cosh(y), \space and \space v=\cosh(x)sinh(y)}$. Cant we also have this curve(s): $\dfrac{u^2}{\sin^2(x)}-\dfrac{v^2}{\cos^2(x)}=\cosh^2(y)-\sinh^2(y)=1$ 

$$\color{green}{for\space 1<\sin(x)\lt1 \space and\space 0<\cos(x)\lt1}$$

i reckon if hold $x=\pi/4$ get $\dfrac{u^2}{\alpha}-\dfrac{v^2}{\alpha}=1$

Comment: Yes, you also get hyperbolas (if you would keep $x$ constant). But you would only get a part of the hyperbolas since $y$ (and $x$) is bounded in the problem. ([example](http://i.imgur.com/GQmhTBH.png)) It's nice when you see that your question (from yesterday) is the same is this one but with a rotation of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ since your question concerned the map $z\mapsto \color{red}{i}\sin z$.